# get server time and add it to js date

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, date

I have date from the server let's say 8/14/2018 12:00pm

I want to get the time only from this date using php  and I believe it's easy with date function, but  how can I add time to javascript date?

For example if I have  in js  this date 7/14/2018   I want to add php time 12:00pm with it  as one date so it will be like  7/14/2018 12:00pm

Is that possible ?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Why not just create a date object with the server time?

Comment: Also have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091372/getting-the-clients-timezone-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the date in js a string. You could do this

```
   <?php 
    // define the datetime object
    $dtDate = new DateTime(‘8/14/2018 12:00pm’);
    ?>

    <!— add it to js —>
    <script>
    var dtDate = “7/14/2018”;
    DtDate = dtDate + “ <?php echo $dtDate->format(H:i); ?>”;
    </script>
```